# Write a file and edit a "placeholder" if the end of the file is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to set a "placeholder" and edit this part later within creating a textfile line by line or do i have to make a linesearch in the end and edit this part?

I would like to count selected lines with constants and if i reached the end of my file, i would like to write the sum of the the list CONSTANTS to the files header.

```
CONSTANTS = []

with open(FILENAME, 'w') as f:

    f.write(str(sum(CONSTANTS)))        # <--- this way its just zero

    f.write('...'); CONSTANTS.append(1)

    f.write('...'); CONSTANTS.append(1)
    .
    .
    .
```

I hope you get what i mean. I am sorry for my english.

**EDIT:**

```
 * MATERIAL, NAME = ...
 * USER MATERIAL, CONSTANTS = **SUM_CONSTANTS*           # <--- sum of CONSTANTS 
 **                                                      #     (In this case: 2)
 *******************************************************
 ** SETTINGS
 *******************************************************
 **
  11, 0, 0, 1,                                           # <--- CONSTANTS.append(1)
 **
 *******************************************************
 ** ...
 *******************************************************
 **
  8.88, 0.0001                                           # <--- CONSTANTS.append(1)
 **
 .
 .
 .
```

It´s a setup file for a simulation. Just for your interests. Don´t know if this information is necessary.

Comment: You could `seek()` back to the beginning of the file and overwrite data there, but the problem will be determining how much space to "reserve" initially since you won't know how much is needed. There are ways to handle that, but without knowing a lot more about the situation/context/constraints, it's difficult to tell which, if any, of them would be suitable.

Comment: @martineau i edited my question. don´t know if its helpful or not. :/ anyway thanks for your fast reply! in this case: do you think seek() is a good solution?

Comment: It looks to me like what you want to write is the **count** of the lines containing constants that were written (not their sum). Regardless, you indeed could make a placeholder comprised of a fixed number of digit characters at a certain spot in the beginning of the file, and initially set them to something like `"00000000"` which is big enough to hold a maximum value of `99999999`. After you write the rest of the file and determine the proper value, you can then `seek()` as I suggested back to that position of the file and overwrite the zeros with the correct digits. i.e. `"00012345"`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to write to the file right away. You may save the data in memory first, then add the header:

```
data = []

data.append("string to write to the file")
# process CONSTANTS

data.insert(0, sum(CONSTANTS))

with open("file", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(line + "\n" for line in map(str, data))
```